# Separate a set of sublists from within a list by a given element of a sublist

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

Input is:

```
 main_list = [['a','1','x'], ['b','2', 'm'], ['a', '23', 'm'], ['c', '34', 'x'], ['b', '11'], ['b', '32', 'y']]
```

Final result should be:

```
 a_list = [['a','1','x'], ['a', '23', 'm']]
 b_list = [['b','2', 'm'], ['b', '32', 'y']]   <-- note that list ['b', '11'] has not been included as it has less elements.
 c_list = ['c', '34', 'x']
```

Personally, I did something like this:

```
 a_list = [[p for p in item] for item in main_list if "a" in item[0]]
 b_list = [[p for p in item] for item in main_list if "b" in item[0] and len(item) > 2]
 c_list = [[p for p in item] for item in main_list if "c" in item[0]]
```

Wondering if there is a way to extract all three lists at once instead of walking `main_list` three times.

To extend the problem, how would you do it if no element is given but your algorithm should sort the sublists by common elements at, let's say, a given position.

Cheers,

Comment: How about a `for` loop?

Comment: `list ['b', '11'] has not been included as it has less elements` Less elements than what?

Comment: For loop is obvious but I want to have it done as list comprehension or even generator for speed and memory saving. More like unpacking a tuple to end up with all three lists at once.

Comment: @Lego: Then the other sublists that are having first element `'b'` and `lenght = 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby` in the `itertools` module will get the information you are looking for (and more):

```
In [31]: main_list = [['a','1','x'], ['b','2', 'm'], ['a', '23', 'm'], ['c', '34', 'x'], ['b', '11'], ['b', '32', 'y']]

In [32]: g = itertools.groupby(main_list, key=lambda x: (x[0], len(x)))
```

To see what is in that generator, run:

```
In [33]: for x in g: print x[0], list(x[1])
('a', 3) [['a', '1', 'x']]
('b', 3) [['b', '2', 'm']]
('a', 3) [['a', '23', 'm']]
('c', 3) [['c', '34', 'x']]
('b', 2) [['b', '11']]
('b', 3) [['b', '32', 'y']]
```

As you can see, this produces information for all lengths.  You are only interested in length=3.  Depending on how you actually want to use the generator, there are a variety of ways to throw away the other lengths.

As an example, this extracts the information from the generator `g` into a dictionary `d` with the results that you were looking for:

```
In [65]: g = itertools.groupby(main_list, key=lambda x: (x[0], len(x)))

In [66]: d = collections.defaultdict(list)

In [67]: for x in g:
    if x[0][1]==3: d[x[0][0]].append(list(x[1])[0])
   ....:     

In [68]: d['a']
Out[68]: [['a', '1', 'x'], ['a', '23', 'm']]

In [69]: d['b']
Out[69]: [['b', '2', 'm'], ['b', '32', 'y']]

In [70]: d['c']
Out[70]: [['c', '34', 'x']]
```

Comment: Great! Except the double `[[]]` in `Out[70`]

Comment: @flamenco As I look at it, each of the dictionary values is a _list_ of _lists_.  Unless you know _ahead of time_ which list of lists is only going to have only one element, you want to keep the double `[[]]`.  Do you see it differently?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the best way is the simplest way. List comprehensions are good, but can get unwieldy and unreadable. They are also no faster than a comparable for loop. The reason you can't convert this into a list comprehension easily is that you will need to append to existing lists to convert 1 list into 3. You might be able to do something using `yield` but that again is quite a bit of work.

```
main_list = [['a','1','x'], ['b','2', 'm'], ['a', '23', 'm'], ['c', '34', 'x'], ['b', '11'], ['b', '32', 'y']]

a_list, b_list, c_list = [],[],[]

for item in main_list:
    if "a" in item[0]:
        a_list.append(item)
    elif "b" in item[0] and len(item) > 2:
        b_list.append(item)
    elif "c" in item[0]:
        c_list.append(item)

print a_list
print b_list
print c_list
```

Outputs:

```
[['a', '1', 'x'], ['a', '23', 'm']]
[['b', '2', 'm'], ['b', '32', 'y']]
[['c', '34', 'x']]
```

Comment: Wondering if your `for` loop can be compressed into a generator or list comprehension?!

Comment: Its unlikely it can be made a list comprehension *easily* or in a way that is readable.

Comment: You have a point in your comment and ...for your comment..:) True, sometimes thriving to save few bytes of memory makes  code unreadable and not worth the pain one has to go through later on by trying to understand your work.